# JMS selector to test if variable exists?

Tags: jms, selector

I want to create a JMS selector to test if a variable exists and if the variable exists, if its value is right. A selector like this :

```
(uid NOT EXISTS) OR (uid='foo')
```

What is the right statement please to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a property value for a name which has not been set is handled as if the
the property exists with a null value.So if a property isn't present, it is treated as null.

In JMS nomenclature it is called a non existent property.

So you can set the JMS selectors as,

```
uid is null or uid='foo'
```